# Linear gradient with multiple backgrounds

Tags: css, background, gradient

What is the syntax for a linear gradient with multiple backgrounds?  My code just produces the yellow instead of a graduation from yellow to pink?

```
background-color: rgba(red,1);
background:
    url(/src/stat/chevronRight.svg) 90% 45% no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(yellow,1) 0%, rgba(pink,1) 100%);
background-size: 7px;
```

Many thanks

Martin

Answer (score 0):

You can set color as word `yellow` or you can use `RGB`, `RGBA` or `Hexadecimal` color values.

```css
div {
  height: 100vh;
  background: url('http://placehold.it/150x150'), linear-gradient(to bottom, yellow, pink);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Hi, many thanks for your help Nenad, your suggestion worked great.